# /bin/sh: 1: python: not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Недавно с винды перешел на Убунту (20.04.2.0) и в vscode теперь не могу код запустить. Через терминал не пробовал (ибо неудобно), установил Code runner и выходит такая ошибка

`/bin/sh: 1: python: not found`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с матом в тексте программа на питоне не работает.

Comment: расширение запрашивает команду `python`, но в `/bin/sh` её нет. либо исправьте расширение, чтобы запрашивал `python3`(? или какая там версия у вас), либо можно сделать симлинк `python` -> `python3`

Comment: Версия питона - 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверь прописан ли путь к python в PATH:

```bsh
echo $PATH
```

Если нет используй export для добавления в PATH

2. Открой терминал и напиши: python. Должно вывести:

```bsh
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Если вывел:

```bsh
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

command 'python3' from deb python3
command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

или

```bsh
python not found, try

apt-get install python
```

Тогда пропиши:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python
```

Comment: Проверь еще все ли необходимые плагины VSC для python у тебя установлены

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Comment: Это сильно обрезанный вариант старого ответа от [polySladkiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1285303/386633)

Comment: Есть разница. В том ответе предлагают установить второй питон, здесь создастся симлинк на третий питон